Windows 11: How to maximize the dialog window by default when clicking the Copilot Preview button in the taskbar?
On Win11 and use Copilot a lot. I'm asking specifically about accessing Copilot by using the Preview button in the bottom right corner of the taskbar. The preview dialog is too small for my tastes, and it's a hassle to fire up Edge every time I want to use Copilot. I'm ok with editing my registry if there's an available tweak. Or any other suggestions welcome.
